# javascript multiplication table order

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have the followign school project:

- You enter a number into a `prompt`
- Highlights every occurance of numbers in interval `[1; 100]` that are the multiplicator of the inputted number.

Issue is, whenever I input a number dividable by `/5` it ruins the table formatting with the extra `<br/>`

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>

        var y = prompt("enter a number between 1 -100 ")
            if( y<=100 && y>=1 ){
                for (i = 1 ; i<=100 ; i++){
                var idk = i + " "
                    if (i%y!=0){
                    document.write(idk)
                    }
                    if(i%10==0 ){
                        document.write("</br>" )
                        console.log(i)
                    }

                     if(i%y==0){

                        document.write(idk.fontcolor("red"))
                    }
                }





            }
            else {
            document.write("your number isnt good")
            }

    </script>
</body>
```

this is my code can someone help me fix it

Comment: I think in the y variable you are getting string instead of number. Check it with typeof operator

Answer (score 0):

**That's because of the order of your `if` conditions.**

If your number is divided by 5, it also by 10. Re-arrange the code structure, so you check for color-ins first and only then apply `<br/>` like so. *(even then, it is a kind of ugly conditional though)*

Basically , just moved `if (i % y == 0) {}` above `if (i % 10 == 0) {}`

```js
let y = prompt("enter a number between 1 -100 ")
if (y <= 100 && y >= 1) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    let idk = i + " "
    if (i % y != 0) {
      document.write(idk)
    }

    if (i % y == 0) {
      document.write(idk.fontcolor("red"))
    }

    if (i % 10 == 0) {
      document.write("</br>")
    }

  }

} else {
  document.write("your number isnt good")
}
```